# alignment using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to align a set of rows using style property

This is the HTML code that is being transformed using XSL

```
<span style="white-space: pre; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Lucida console, Courier ">&lt;40      : item1</span><br>
<span style="white-space: pre; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Lucida console, Courier ">40-80    : item2 </span><br>
```

What is needed is how to align items like

```
<40      : item1
40-80    : item2
```

currently it appears like

```
<40 : item1
40-80 : item2
```

is this possible using style property?

using Internet explorer version 6 & above

Comment: It has a marginal relation to `xslt` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `char` attribute for HTML `td` tags, *however*, it is not at all supported as far as I know.

This is valid HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr char=".">
    <td>11.10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr char=".">
    <td>111.20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr char=".">
    <td>15552.52</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have used this workaround in the past:

http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/javascript/table-align-char/

Answer (score 0):

use `&nbsp;` instead of spaces

Comment: since this is being transformed using XSL, is it possible to determine the number of nbsp; needed per item?

Comment: nbsp; is not advisable as the font size n spacing for each characters might have different width

Comment: if the font size differs then it is almost impossible to do it the way the OP asked

Comment: @lilsizzo: that won't be a problem here, balalakshmi is using a fixed-width font.

Comment: font size differs as in the width for each characters might be different. 0 is much wider than 1. thus &nbsp; cant be be displayed as it should. so on and so forth for the rest of the characters.

Comment: i know what you ment. but you can change the font to fixedwidth, and if you cant its almost impossible to do it in a single node

Comment: hmm i see Courier is a monospace font aka fixed width. but this is relying on the client pc to display the font. perhaps he can cater this lack of stability by using webfont

Answer (score 0):

sure it is possible. u can use

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50px">&lt; 40</div><div style="float: left; ">:</div><div style="float: left; ">item 1</div>
 <span style='clear: left'></span>
 <div style="float: left; width: 50px"> 40</div><div style="float: left; ">:</div><div style="float: left; ">item 2</div>
```

or else you could try

```
display: table-cell;
```

it can be put in the styling.

Comment: thats a lot of floating divs.. i think you should try and KISS :)

Comment: lol yeah guess it is a lot. its given because div is using display: block. withouth using display block, width in the style would have no effect thus the float exist. unless the ":" and "items1" can be replaced to span as its not needed for the white spaces. haven heard of KISS. funny name though =)

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: pre;` should do the trick and work in all browsers..

- do you get this error in every browser or just in IE?
- are there any other stylesheeds affecting these `<span>`-elements?
- is it possible to change the xsl to get another markup?

Answer (score 0):

many options:

If you can wrap range (ex 40-80) and item name (ex item1) in separate element, then define width for each.

Otherwise, specify `white-space: pre` so that whitespace preserved by the browser. 
Don't forget to use [Monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) so that each character each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. 
example: Consolas, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace